# Django - Permission denied to open media in production server (Azure)

Tags: python, django

Now i am working on production server (AzureWebsites) and i want to open my `.txt` files.

This is the tree that i used to save my `stopwords.txt`

```
-App
  -media
      -App
         stopwords.txt
  -static
  -templates
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media').replace('\\', '/')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I want to open the text file using this command

```
handle = open('/media/stopwords.txt', 'r+')
var = handle.read()
```

This is the error i got when run my app

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/stopwords.txt'
```

and when i try to modify the **open** statements with this

```
handle = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'stopwords.txt', 'r+')
```

i got this error

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/home/site/wwwroot/mediastopwords.txt'
```

Can anyone please help fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `handle = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/stopwords.txt', 'r+')`

Comment: not working on me sir. can you please give other advise? @Andrei Anischevici

Comment: Please open up an Explorer, browse to the stopwords.txt in it and paste the full path to it here.

Comment: E:\Workspace\djvs\plags\plags\prkplagiarism\media\prkplagiarism\stopwords.txt

(fyi, i did deploy my app to azurewebsites)

Comment: So this means the path you've provided is on your local machine, not on the Azure server? In case you're running the app locally, the problem is with your PROJECT_ROOT, which should be set to `E:\Workspace\djvs\plags\plags\prkplagiarism` instead of `D:/home/site/wwwroot/media/prkplagiarism`

Comment: In case you're running the app remotely on the Azure server, you must setup the PROJECT_ROOT according to your app location on the server, which you can get by ftp-ing or ssh-ing to the server and seeing what the path to your app is..

Comment: Sure, that is the answer. Working on me sir. I change the path and replace it with path on server. PATH on Azure='D:/home/site/wwwroot/prkplagiarism/media/prkplagiarism/file.txt' @Andrei Anischevici

Answer (score 0):

According to your tree stopwords is stored under /media/App/stopwords.txt
So to open it you need:

```
handle = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/App/stopwords.txt', 'r+')
```

Comment: still not working sir (i deploy my web on azure server). new error: No such file or directory: 'D:/home/site/wwwroot/media/prkplagiarism/stopwords.txt'. (prkplagiarism = App) @Aldarund